# Visual studio при отладке не ловит null исключения unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio

Я имею ввиду что если в игре возникал null exception то debug в Visual Studio ловил его его автоматически останавливаясь на строчке где произошло это исключение, но сейчас останавливаеться только там где указали.Короче не пойму что такое поставил в  редакторе unity в консоли Error Pause буду хоть так нулл отлавливать.

Comment: Ну VS в дебаге останавливает выполнение на не обработанных исключениях. Если сейчас у вас не останавливается выполнение, значит это исключение у вас обрабатывается (возникает исключение в блоке try-catch)

Comment: Нет ничего не обрабатываеться